# How do you convert the JSON below to a Codable Struct?

Tags: ios, swift, codable

I have some JSON that I need to parse and process within my tvOS app.  I've tried using the website quicktype.io to convert the JSON to a struct, but it comes back with nothing.  I think it's because of the layout of the JSON.

What would be the proper codable struct to handle this data?

```
{
   "bnn":[
      "prod",
      "staging"
   ],
   "bravo":[
      "prod"
   ],
   "comedy":[
      "prod"
   ],
   "cp24":[
      "prod"
   ],
   "crave":[
      "prod",
      "french"
   ],
   "ctv":[
      "prod",
      "prod-empty",
      "prod-broken",
      "chromecast-enabled",
      "chromecast-enabled-is-enabled-empty",
      "chromecast-enabled-some-text",
      "chromecast-enabled-configpath-wrongurl",
      "chromecast-disabled",
      "adobe-heartbeat-enabled-false",
      "adobe-heartbeat-enabled-true",
      "adobe-heartbeat-is-enabled-empty",
      "adobe-heartbeat-is-enabled-some-text",
      "ads-enabled-live-disable",
      "ads-enabled-live-empty",
      "ads-enabled-live-enable",
      "ads-enabled-live-some-text",
      "ads-enabled-vod-disable",
      "ads-enabled-vod-empty",
      "ads-enabled-vod-enable",
      "ads-enabled-vod-some-text",
      "chromecast-enabled-applicationid-empty",
      "chromecast-enabled-upnext-empty",
      "chromecast-enabled-wrong-applicationid",
      "chromecast-upnext-disabled",
      "chromecast-upnext-enabled",
      "chromecast-upnext-isenabled-empty",
      "chromecast-upnext-isenabled-some-text",
      "chromecast-upnext-namescape-some-text",
      "chromecast-upnext-namespace-empty",
      "closed-captioning-disabled",
      "closed-captioning-enabled",
      "closed-captioning-enabled-empty",
      "closed-captioning-enabled-some-text",
      "comscore-enabled-false",
      "comscore-is-enabled-empty",
      "comscore-is-enabled-some-text",
      "comscore-publisher-id-empty",
      "comscore-publisher-id-some-text",
      "comscore-secret-empty",
      "comscore-secret-some-text",
      "conviva-customer-key-empty",
      "conviva-customer-key-some-text",
      "conviva-enabled-empty",
      "conviva-enabled-false",
      "conviva-enabled-some-text",
      "conviva-enabled-true",
      "conviva-product-type-empty",
      "conviva-product-type-some-text",
      "conviva-url-empty",
      "conviva-url-some-text",
      "enable-endscreen-disabled",
      "enable-endscreen-empty",
      "enable-endscreen-some-text",
      "enable-episode-list-disabled",
      "enable-episode-list-empty",
      "enable-episode-list-enabled",
      "enable-episode-list-some-text",
      "enable-shareable-disabled",
      "enable-shareable-empty",
      "enable-shareable-enabled",
      "enable-shareable-some-text",
      "enable-upnext-disabled",
      "enable-upnext-empty",
      "enable-upnext-enabled",
      "enable-upnext-some-text",
      "endscreen-enabled",
      "krux-brand-empty",
      "krux-brand-some-text",
      "krux-id-empty",
      "krux-id-some-text",
      "krux-is-enabled-empty",
      "krux-is-enabled-false",
      "krux-is-enabled-some-text",
      "krux-is-enabled-true",
      "krux-type-empty",
      "krux-type-some-text",
      "language-empty",
      "language-enabled-en",
      "language-enabled-fr",
      "language-some-text",
      "location-services-disable",
      "location-services-empty",
      "location-services-enable",
      "location-services-some-text",
      "moat-enabled-false",
      "moat-enabled-true",
      "moat-html5partnercode-missing",
      "moat-html5partnercode-some-text",
      "moat-is-enabled-empty",
      "moat-is-enabled-some-text",
      "omniture-channel-empty",
      "omniture-channel-some-text",
      "omniture-enabled-empty",
      "omniture-enabled-false",
      "omniture-enabled-some-text",
      "omniture-enabled-true",
      "omniture-phonetrackingid-empty",
      "omniture-phonetrackingid-some-text",
      "omniture-server-empty",
      "omniture-server-some-text",
      "omniture-tablettrackingid-empty",
      "omniture-tablettrackingid-some-text",
      "omniture-video-player-name-empty",
      "omniture-video-player-name-some-text",
      "show-cellular-streaming-message-disabled",
      "show-cellular-streaming-message-empty",
      "show-cellular-streaming-message-enabled",
      "show-cellular-streaming-message-some-text",
      "upnext-duration-disabled",
      "upnext-duration-empty",
      "upnext-duration-enabled",
      "upnext-duration-some-text",
      "upnext-offset-disabled",
      "upnext-offset-empty",
      "upnext-offset-enabled",
      "upnext-offset-some-text",
      "video-wifi-or-wifi-and-cell-disabled",
      "video-wifi-or-wifi-and-cell-empty",
      "video-wifi-or-wifi-and-cell-enabled",
      "video-wifi-or-wifi-and-cell-some-text"
   ],
   "ctv_news":[
      "prod"
   ],
   "ctvhub":[
      "prod"
   ],
   "ctvcomedy":[
      "prod"
   ],
   "ctvdrama":[
      "prod"
   ],
   "dgo":[
      "prod"
   ],
   "e_brand":[
      "prod"
   ],
   "rds":[
      "prod"
   ],
   "se":[
      "prod"
   ],
   "snackable":[
      "prod"
   ],
   "space":[
      "prod"
   ],
   "tsn":[
      "prod"
   ],
   "vidiqa":[
      "prod"
   ],
   "vidiqa111":[
      "prod",
      "omniture-server-empty"
   ]
}
```

Please advise?

Comment: [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/?l=swift) can help you.

Comment: It can't actually, that's what I indicated in my description...

Comment: *It comes back with nothing* is not true. The suggested type `[String: [String]]` is indeed the common denominator. Otherwise add a property for each key and declare it as `[String]` for example `let bnn : [String]`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to type out the whole struct for you, but a start would be

```
struct MyData: Codable {
   let bnn: [String]
   let bravo: [String]
   let comedy: [String]
   let cp24: [String]
   let brave: [String]
   // and so on until
   let vidiqa111: [String]
}
```

and if those string values are fixed, you could define an enum for them:

```
enum StringValue: String {
   case prod
   case staging
   case french
   // ...
}
```

and change the struct's properties to be of type `[StringValue]`.

If you're fine with using just strings in dictionaries/arrays, you can also simply use what quicktype.io suggests:

```
typealias MyData = [String: [String]]
let myData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(MyData.self, from: jsonData)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think all I need to do is to assign the data coming back to a dictionary where the key is a string and the value is an array of strings.

Comment: In that case, quicktype.io gave you precisely what you needed: `[String: [String]]`.

Comment: Cool, thanks.. I think I was expecting it to create a struct..

Comment: Usually you do, and moving away from stringly-typed APIs is almost always a good idea, but using a simple typealias is certainly also possible.